# Cómo hacer para que el fragment no cargue de nuevo

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, recyclerview

tengo 2 fragments que se muestra 1 por vez en un framelayout. El problema es que cuando vuelvo a tocar para ver el fragment anterior éste tiene un recycler view y vuelve a cargar los items, o sea si habia 4 items vuelve a cargar de vuelta los 4 items otra vez y entonces se terminan mostrando 8 items en pantalla. Dejo el código para ver si me ayudan.

Código de la activity

```
public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity {


    Chats chats = new Chats();
    Grupos grupos = new Grupos();
    TextView chatsTab, groupsTab;
    boolean ch = true, gr = false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

        chatsTab = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chats_tab);
        groupsTab = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.groups_tab);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_chats_groups,chats).commit();

        chatsTab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (gr){
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_chats_groups,chats);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    chatsTab.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.colorBlanco));
                    groupsTab.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.colorBlancoTransparente));
                    gr = false;
                    ch = true;
                }
            }
        });

        groupsTab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ch){
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_chats_groups,grupos);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    groupsTab.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.colorBlanco));
                    chatsTab.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.colorBlancoTransparente));
                    ch = false;
                    gr = true;
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Código del fragments Chats

```
public class Chats extends Fragment {

    public Chats() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    RecyclerView parejas_list, chats_list;
    ParejasAdapter parejasAdapter;
    ChatsAdapter chatsAdapter;
    List<Pareja> parejaList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Chat> chatList = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false);

        parejas_list = v.findViewById(R.id.parejas_list);
        chats_list = v.findViewById(R.id.chats_list);

        parejaList.add(new Pareja(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul));
        parejaList.add(new Pareja(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul));
        parejaList.add(new Pareja(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul));
        parejaList.add(new Pareja(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul));
        parejaList.add(new Pareja(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul));
        parejaList.add(new Pareja(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul));
        parejaList.add(new Pareja(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul));
        parejaList.add(new Pareja(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul));
        parejaList.add(new Pareja(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul));



        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL,false);
        parejas_list.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        parejasAdapter = new ParejasAdapter(getContext(),parejaList);
        parejas_list.setAdapter(parejasAdapter);


        chatList.add(new Chat(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul,"Pablo","Holaa",1));
        chatList.add(new Chat(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul,"Pablo","Holaa",4));
        chatList.add(new Chat(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul,"Pablo","Holaa",0));
        chatList.add(new Chat(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul,"Pablo","Holaa",0));
        chatList.add(new Chat(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul,"Pablo","Holaa",0));
        chatList.add(new Chat(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul,"Pablo","Holaa",2));
        chatList.add(new Chat(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul,"Pablo","Holaa",1));



        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManagerChats = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false);
        chats_list.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerChats);
        chatsAdapter = new ChatsAdapter(getContext(),chatList);
        chats_list.setAdapter(chatsAdapter);

        return v;
    }
}
```

XML de la activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.MainMenu"
    android:background="@drawable/view_background_main_menu"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_options"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/image_avenlife_logo"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            app:civ_circle_background_color="@color/colorBlanco"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chats_tab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text="Chats"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:fontFamily="@font/barlow_semi_bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlanco"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/groups_tab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text="Grupos"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:fontFamily="@font/barlow_semi_bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlancoTransparente"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_chats_groups"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

XML del fragment Chats

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments_main_menu.Chats"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorBlancoTransFondoParejas">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="PAREJAS"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/barlow_medium_italic"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlanco"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"/>
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/parejas_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CHATS"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/barlow_medium_italic"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlanco"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"/>
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/chats_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

El código del otro fragment no lo pongo porque esta "vacío" porque todavía no lo programé pero tiene otro recycler view.

Comment: La lista la tienes creada como miembro de la clase y solo haces `new` cuando la defines. Cada vez que se llama a `onCreateView` añades elementos, así que mientras no se destruya y se reconstruya el objeto de la clase, la variable de la lista no se inicializa. Cada vez que vuelves al fragment, se llama a `onCreateView`, pero sobre el mismo objeto. Así que tendrías que hacer `new` a la lista antes de meter elementos, en cada `onCreateView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recuerda que se esta llamando el metodo `onCreateView()` del Fragment nuevamente, si este no se destruyo como es este caso, los datos se agregaràn nuevamente a las listas y por lo tanto a tu Adapter.

Debes inicializar las listas dentro de `onCreateView()`:

```
List<Pareja> parejaList; // = new ArrayList<>();
List<Chat> chatList; // = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false);

    parejas_list = v.findViewById(R.id.parejas_list);
    chats_list = v.findViewById(R.id.chats_list);

    //Inicializa listas.
    parejaList = new ArrayList<>();
    chatList = new ArrayList<>();

    parejaList.add(new Pareja(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul));
    parejaList.add(new Pareja(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul));
    parejaList.add(new Pareja(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul));
    parejaList.add(new Pareja(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul));
    parejaList.add(new Pareja(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul));
    parejaList.add(new Pareja(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul));
    parejaList.add(new Pareja(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul));
    parejaList.add(new Pareja(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul));
    parejaList.add(new Pareja(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul));



    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL,false);
    parejas_list.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    parejasAdapter = new ParejasAdapter(getContext(),parejaList);
    parejas_list.setAdapter(parejasAdapter);


    chatList.add(new Chat(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul,"Pablo","Holaa",1));
    chatList.add(new Chat(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul,"Pablo","Holaa",4));
    chatList.add(new Chat(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul,"Pablo","Holaa",0));
    chatList.add(new Chat(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul,"Pablo","Holaa",0));
    chatList.add(new Chat(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul,"Pablo","Holaa",0));
    chatList.add(new Chat(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul,"Pablo","Holaa",2));
    chatList.add(new Chat(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul,"Pablo","Holaa",1));



    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManagerChats = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false);
    chats_list.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerChats);
    chatsAdapter = new ChatsAdapter(getContext(),chatList);
    chats_list.setAdapter(chatsAdapter);

    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te esta faltando inicializar las listas

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false);

   initData();
   ...
}

private initData(){
   parejaList = new ArrayList<>();      
   parejaList.add(new Pareja(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul));
   parejaList.add(new Pareja(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul));
   ...

   chatList = new ArrayList<>();
   chatList.add(new Chat(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul,"Pablo","Holaa",1));
   chatList.add(new Chat(R.drawable.icon_logo_chico_avenlife_azul,"Pablo","Holaa",4));
   ...
}
```